# Wordpress themes with built in product catalog

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want a product catalog without the e-commerce flashy stuff.
I have found one theme so far that has this integrated very nicely

http://themeforest.net/item/nimble-multipurpose-retina-ready-wordpress-theme/3009347

I was wondering if there were more themes out there that had a product catalog similar to this theme.

I tried catablog, works really well, but I don't like how it treats the products as blog posts, and most themes show the "0 comments By username" under the post.

I am looking for themes with a built in catalog, such as nimble. Or really good plugins that get a long nicely with wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mentioned that you're not keen on having products as posts, but I think this is a good fit for Wordpress. Doing it this way will permit you to attach unlimited metadata items to your products, and is in keeping with the 'Wordpress way' of doing things.

If you don't want to see pagination devices on your post browsing pages, modify the "index.php" of the theme, ideally in a child theme, so that the parent theme can easily be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like Catablog just for the reason that it has 0 and 1 comment listed, it is possible to delete that part of the code. If you can post the single.php file then I can help you in removing that part of code.

Answer (score 0):

There are also some other WordPress catalog plugins which are nice to consider. For example eCommerce Product Catalog doesn't show meta data like in a post. It goes a long nicely with WordPress: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ecommerce-product-catalog/